# How to replace Hurlstack for Volley?

Tags: android, request, android-volley

I see an issue with the Volley library with respect to their DELETE method. If you look at the HurlStack class, and find setConnectionParametersForRequest() method, you will see the following:

```
static void setConnectionParametersForRequest(HttpURLConnection connection, Request<?> request) throws IOException, AuthFailureError {
    switch(request.getMethod()) {
    case -1:
        byte[] postBody = request.getPostBody();
        if(postBody != null) {
            connection.setDoOutput(true);
            connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
            connection.addRequestProperty("Content-Type", request.getPostBodyContentType());
            DataOutputStream out = new DataOutputStream(connection.getOutputStream());
            out.write(postBody);
            out.close();
        }
        break;
    case 0:
        connection.setRequestMethod("GET");
        break;
    case 1:
        connection.setRequestMethod("POST");
        addBodyIfExists(connection, request);
        break;
    case 2:
        connection.setRequestMethod("PUT");
        addBodyIfExists(connection, request);
        break;
    case 3:
        connection.setRequestMethod("DELETE");
        break;
    default:
        throw new IllegalStateException("Unknown method type.");
    }

}
```

Notice that the DELETE method does not have "addBodyIfExists(connection, request)". This is an issue because now if you use the DELETE method and you want/need to include a body you are not able to. My question is, how can I replace this HurlStack and use a custom HurlStack where I can include the body for my DELETE method?

Comment: Pass your custom Http stack implementation in the RequestQueue factory method: RequestQueue.newRequestQueue(context, stack)

Comment: @BladeCoder can you post your answer? I will accept it. This looks like it works.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Pass your custom `HttpStack` implementation in the RequestQueue factory method:

```
HttpStack stack = new MyHurlStack();
RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(context, stack);
```